# What creature did Boba encounter while digging for water?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, the-book-of-boba-fett

In S01E01 of the *The Book of Boba Fett*, "Stranger in a Strange Land", during a flashback scene Boba is tasked by a Tusken villager to dig for water pods with another captive.

During this digging process the Rodian captive uncovers a claw which is quickly revealed to be attached to a large 6 armed/legged monster. To my knowledge this creature has not been seen in the Star Wars galaxy before. It is quite unique as it has ability to switch its 6 appendages between 2 arms and 4 legs to 4 arms and 2 legs.

In the end...

> Boba Fett defeats the creat by choking it with the chains he was bound with and taking the decapitated head back to the Tusken village.

**What is the name of the species this creature belongs to?**

Is it native to Tatooine or can it be found on other systems as well?

[image]

Comment: So far, it's unnamed, but the producers have stated that it's a tribute to Ray Harryhausen and the Kraken from *Clash of the Titans*.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_six-limbed_creature - Currently unnamed

Comment: @Valorum that qualifies as an answer I think

Comment: @PeterNielsen - You are welcome to display your ignorance. I prefer to wait until there's an answer :-)

Comment: I'm not going to take someone else's research and write it into my own answer... if you're going to wait until there *is* a name, be my guest.

Comment: The audio description for the episode refers to it as a "behemoth". It's not clear whether that's its actual name or merely a description, noting that the official subs refer to it as a "sand creature"

Comment: The buzz on Reddit and YT is that it is a creature called a logra, which was mentioned in two Legends writings and one Disney-era short story

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This creature is known as a **Tatooine sand beast** according to [the Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine-sand-beast).

[image: Screenshot of Databank entry for Tatooine Sand Beast]

> ##### TATOOINE SAND BEAST
>
> Feral beasts that lurk beneath the sands of Tatooine, sand beasts spring up seemingly out of nowhere to startle, stun, and maim their prey. The creatures are one of innumerable hazards for anyone trekking across the endless desert. For the Tusken Raiders, tangling with a sand beast can win praise and respect.
>
> <sub>(source: https://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine-sand-beast)</sub>

Its only location is listed as Tatooine, so it may be a native species.

Its Databank entry previously gave its name as ["Tatooine sand ape"](https://web.archive.org/web/20220714223513/https://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine-sand-ape), but this seems to have been changed in [July or August of 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20220803202620/https://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine-sand-beast) for unknown reasons:

[image: Screenshot of Databank entry for Tatooine Sand Ape]

Comment: That's such an unremarkable name.... and in what way is it an ape! I'm not blaming you, nice find!

Comment: It’s much more evocative in the original Tusken.